# VS 2013 Express for Desktop wont open vcxproj project files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to open the Direct3D Tutorial Win32 Samples with VS 2013 Express for Windows Desktop. To my surprise it claims that the individuals projects in the solution each cannot be opened because their project types (.vcxproj) are not supported by this version of the application.

Does anyone know why the vcxproj files cannot be opened, or how I could diagnose and repair the root cause of the problem?

Edit: I can also not open the vcxproj files in [Mike Farnsworth's Rayito project](https://github.com/Tecla/Rayito).

Comment: I'm not familiar with .vcxproj files but have seen similar issues with .csproj files. You could check if your .vcxproj files contain something like a `<ProjectTypeGuids>` element. This node is created for special projects to be recogized by VS add-ins. Usually removing this element allows you to open the project.

Comment: Can you create a new C++ project in that instance of VS 2013 Express?

Comment: @Nicknow Smart question! I can create them, but once I close them, I cannot open them up again, with the same error that this version of the application cannot open them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the other answers seemed to help.

I uninstalled visual studio. I uninstalled SQL server. I reinstalled visual studio. Now it loads C++ projects correctly.

I understand a previous install of visual studio can cause the problem I was having. Apparently so can installing SQL server Express prior to installing Visual Studio 2013 Express.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the projects were created in another version of Visual Studio.

Try to upgrade the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting Upgrade Solution.

Alternatively you could use Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition to see if that resolves the problem.

[Windows Dev Center](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef) indicates that Visual Studio 2012 is required.

Hope this helps