# error to open new project via Visual studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

The error I get when trying to open new project in visual studio:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS 2013 Express for Desktop wont open vcxproj project files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569028/vs-2013-express-for-desktop-wont-open-vcxproj-project-files)

Comment: Install the C++ tools in VS2015 setup